# get_meta on variable check-out process (Cart, check-out, emails)

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I create some custom field for my product in Woocommerce. Everything is working fine for the single product part.

But for the variable product: meta info are visible on the product page then disappear for the cart, check-out, and emails. If someone is ok to check my code I'll be more than grateful :).

Thanks a lot.

```
/**
 Display info
 **/

// Admin: Add custom field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'vp_add_pp_info' );
function vp_add_pp_info(){

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_venue',
        'label'       => __('Venue', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Venue here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the Venue of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_date',
        'label'       => __('Date', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Date here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the Date of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_time',
        'label'       => __('Time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Time here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the time of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

// Admin: Save custom field value for simple product inventory options
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'vp_product_save_pp_info', 10, 1 );
function vp_product_save_pp_info( $product ){
    if( isset($_POST['_venue']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_venue', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_venue']) );

    if( isset($_POST['_date']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_date']) );

    if( isset($_POST['_time']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_time', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_time']) );
}


// Frontend: Display PP Info on product
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'vp_product_display_pp_info' );
function vp_product_display_pp_info() {
    global $product;

    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_venue' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
        ': </i>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_date' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
        ': </i>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_time' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
        ': </i>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
}

// Frontend: Display PP Info on product variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'vp_variation_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_variation_display_pp_info( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_venue' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

        if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_date' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

        if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_time' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

    return $data;
}



// Frontend: Display info on cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'vp_cart_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_cart_display_pp_info( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item_name .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item_name .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

     if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item_name .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}



// Frontend: Display info on checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'vp_checkout_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_checkout_display_pp_info( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}





// Save PP Info to order items (and display it on admin orders)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'vp_order_item_save_pp_info', 10, 4 );
function vp_order_item_save_pp_info( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_venue', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

     if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_date', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

      if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_time', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

    return $item_qty;
}

// Frontend & emails: Display PP Info on orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'vp_order_item_display_pp_info', 10, 4 );
function vp_order_item_display_pp_info( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    // Not on admin
    //if( is_admin() ) return;

    if( $value = $item->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $value = '<i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") . ':</i> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="pp-info"><p>' . $value . '</p></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }

      if( $value = $item->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $value = '<i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") . ':</i> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="pp-info"><p>' . $value . '</p></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }

      if( $value = $item->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $value = '<i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") . ':</i> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="pp-info"><p>' . $value . '</p></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above hook and add the product meta only for further operation to see in cart and the checkout page and then in order view page you have to use below hooks.

1) for adding meta

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array($this,'addProductToCart' ), 10, 2 );
```

2) setting meta in session

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', array($this, 'get_cart_item_from_session' ), 10, 2);
```

3) retrieve and display the meta in checkout and cart page

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', array($this,'getting_car_item_data' ), 10, 2);
```

If you still have any issue please comment

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for taking the time and for your answer. I'm new in PHP so I'm struggling to understand the solution. Maybe It'll be easier for you with the all code. Thanks, Marie

Comment: okay so you can put the code above let me check what's wrong with the code why it's not display in cart & checkout.

Comment: Hello, Oh I'm sorry, I thought you were going to check my code above. It' why I didn't reply. I tried but it didn't work :(. Indeed, my item data are displaying on the Woocommerce processes. So it's working fine for the singles product. It's only for the variable (multiple option choice) products where it doesn't work on the cart and check-out page. Thanks a lot for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for taking the time and for your answer. I'm new in PHP so I'm struggling to understand the solution. Maybe It'll be easier for you with all code. Thanks, Marie

```
/**
 Display info
 **/

// Admin: Add custom field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'vp_add_pp_info' );
function vp_add_pp_info(){

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_venue',
        'label'       => __('Venue', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Venue here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the Venue of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_date',
        'label'       => __('Date', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Date here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the Date of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_time',
        'label'       => __('Time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Time here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the time of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

// Admin: Save custom field value for simple product inventory options
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'vp_product_save_pp_info', 10, 1 );
function vp_product_save_pp_info( $product ){
    if( isset($_POST['_venue']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_venue', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_venue']) );

    if( isset($_POST['_date']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_date']) );

    if( isset($_POST['_time']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_time', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_time']) );
}


// Frontend: Display PP Info on product
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'vp_product_display_pp_info' );
function vp_product_display_pp_info() {
    global $product;

    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_venue' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
        ': </i>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_date' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
        ': </i>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_time' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
        ': </i>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
}

// Frontend: Display PP Info on product variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'vp_variation_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_variation_display_pp_info( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_venue' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

        if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_date' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

        if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_time' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

    return $data;
}



// Frontend: Display info on cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'vp_cart_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_cart_display_pp_info( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item_name .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item_name .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

     if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item_name .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}



// Frontend: Display info on checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'vp_checkout_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_checkout_display_pp_info( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<p class="product-pp-info"><i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
            ':</i> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}





// Save PP Info to order items (and display it on admin orders)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'vp_order_item_save_pp_info', 10, 4 );
function vp_order_item_save_pp_info( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_venue', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

     if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_date', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

      if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_time', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

    return $item_qty;
}

// Frontend & emails: Display PP Info on orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'vp_order_item_display_pp_info', 10, 4 );
function vp_order_item_display_pp_info( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    // Not on admin
    //if( is_admin() ) return;

    if( $value = $item->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $value = '<i>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") . ':</i> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="pp-info"><p>' . $value . '</p></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }

      if( $value = $item->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $value = '<i>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") . ':</i> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="pp-info"><p>' . $value . '</p></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }

      if( $value = $item->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $value = '<i>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") . ':</i> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="pp-info"><p>' . $value . '</p></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }


}
```